# How to display image as convert varbinary(max) from SQL Server to image in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My image storing format is File -> `byte[]` -> `string base64` -> `varbinary(max)`.

My image retrieve format is `varbinary(max)` -> `byte[]` -> then image format.

But I can not display the image.

Please help retrieve the image format.

Comment: Drop the `string base64` step in the storing process - you're not doing that in the retrieval, and if you're storing in `Varbinary(max)`, it's also totally unnecessary and pointless

Comment: Thank u marc,i was drop the string base 64,which step is correct way of retrieve the image format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What mime type of your image?
Maybe you need a method `Controller.File(fileContents: yourByteArray, contentType: "image/jpeg")`

For example:

```
// Represent a image.
public class MyImage
{
    public ID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; } 
}
```

Upload image:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            var image = new MyImage() 
            {
                MimeType = file.ContentType,
                Data = new byte[file.ContentLength]
            }  

            file.InputStream.Read(image.Data, 0, file.ContentLength); 
        }

        repository.SaveImage(image);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

Get image:

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int imageID)
{
    var image = repository.Images.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == imageID);

    if (image != null)
    {
         return File(image.Data, image.MimeType); 
    }
    else
       return null;
}
```

View: show image

```
@model YourApp.Entities.MyImage

<div class="item">

        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "YourController", 
             new { Model.ID })" />
 </div>
```

Comment: How to implement this method

Comment: hai sp,My database image column is varbinary(MAX),how to retrieve again file format,please tel me

Comment: You need to use File() method. For example `File(image.Data, image.MimeType);` image.MimeType is file format (png, jpeg etc). image.Data is data from DB column